# Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'localhost:90,localhost:90'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I am trying to configure nginx along with Gunicorn for a Django project. nginx is giving me the following error:

```
DisallowedHost at /
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'localhost:90,localhost:90'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.
```

This is my nginx configuration

```
    server {

        listen 90;
        listen [::]:90;

        server_name xxxx;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
            root /home/user/djangopro/djangoapp;
        }

        location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_redirect off;

            proxy_pass http://localhost:8200/;
        }
    }
```

Gunicorn is serving the site properly at `localhost:8200`. Can anyone tell me what is causing the error?

Comment: why using `90` other than `80` .Any reason ?

Comment: `HTTP_HOST` must contain a single domain name with optionally a port number, not a comma-delimited list of domains. I can't tell why it's set to an invalid value.

Comment: what i need to change =@knbk

Comment: try `listen [::]:90;` to `listen [::]:90 ipv6only=on;`

Answer (score 10):

I was getting the same error. I'm guessing you might be coming from Flask converting to Django? If you remove the `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;` line from your configuration, it should work (it fixed my error). I think what that does is stack together both the requesting ip address, and the proxy ip address, while Django only wants a single ip address, not a list. See this Django ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28028

I'm guessing you already got this figured out (since its been a few months), but I'm still answering to save someone the 2 hours I just spent googling :)

edit: I'd like to clarify, the problem comes from having both `include proxy_params;` and `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;` set. The default `proxy_params` already have the `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;` included, so it'll set the host twice, hence the list of two hosts. Look at the `proxy_params` file in `/etc/nginx/proxy_params` if you're on Ubuntu (will be a similar path on other machines).

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issue with docker because I'm trying to call a django service from another container.

Ended up doing a monkey patch in settings.py since all this method does is actually check / match the domain. Could be a security issue, do at your own risk.

```
# monkey patch to get rid of message below in docker
from django.http.request import HttpRequest
HttpRequest.get_host = HttpRequest._get_raw_host
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, too, and discovered that Django actually has a reference to it, [buried obscurely in its docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/).

The solution is to implement a custom middleware, though in my case I had to modify the middleware suggested in the docs. Here is my modified middleware, and the line in settings.py where I added it:

custom.middleware.py:

```
class MultipleProxyMiddleware:
   FORWARDED_FOR_FIELDS = [
    'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',
    'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST',
    'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER',
    'HTTP_HOST' <=== I ADDED THIS LINE
]

def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response = get_response

def __call__(self, request):
    """
    Rewrites the proxy headers so that only the most
    recent proxy is used.
    """
    for field in self.FORWARDED_FOR_FIELDS:
        if field in request.META:
            if ',' in request.META[field]:
                parts = request.META[field].split(',')
                request.META[field] = parts[-1].strip()
    return self.get_response(request)
```

settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'my.apps.custom.middleware.MultipleProxyMiddleware', <=== I added this line
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'axes.middleware.AxesMiddleware',
]
```